# Binary complement 0 to 1, 1 to 0

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a number , let say 4 which is in binary represented as 100 , what i will like to achieve is to complement the number i.e. replace 1 by 0 and 0 by 1 . I can achieve it like this

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(4);

        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        char[] chars = binaryString.toCharArray();
        char x;
        for (char ch : chars) {
            if (ch == '1') {
                x = '0';
            } else {
                x = '1';
            }
            out.append(x);
        }
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(out.toString(), 2));
    }
}
```

What is the most efficient way to achieve the same result in terms of time complexity?  Please note that input can be very big numbers and we need to take care of Integer overflow.

**Updated**
negating a number like ~n will give wrong result , for e.g.

```
System.out.println(~4); 
outputs -5 , expected 3
```

Comment: How wide are the input numbers considered to be? Why does `100` go to `011` instead of, say, `11111011`? Should `10` go to `01` or to `101`?

Comment: Also, if the inputs can be too big to fit in an int, how are you receiving them? Text input on stdin?

Comment: And what about using bitwise negation (`~`)?

Comment: Convert to string and use .replaceAll()

Comment: @user2357112 Because the input is number 4, which is represented in binary 100, and we need to negate that number. In general input can be any positive number and we need to negate the number.

Comment: Why not use replaceAll()

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do. Say your value is 4, therefore `100`. What do you want printed? `0...<plentyoftimes>011` or `011`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the most efficient way to achieve the same result in terms of time complexity?

Given that the size of `int` is fixed at 32, the time complexity is O(1). Your program is pretty inefficient, though, because it creates a coupe of strings, does string parsing, and so on.

You can do this faster if you skip the conversion to binary altogether, and simply invert the number, like this:

```
int val = 4;
int msb = int msb = 32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(val);
int inverse = ~val & ((1 << msb)-1);
System.out.println(inverse);
```

The `~` operator is a unary operator that produces a binary complement of the value. The loop computes the position of the most significant bit (MSB). `((1 << msb)-1)` is a mask that removes all bits higher than the MSB.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/EA0ZRN)

Comment: note that this will also flip the sign bit, resulting in -5 rather than 3.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow and so will this operator in pretty much all other programming languages where it exists, no surprise here

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow You are right, OP wants a positive number. I added code to pay attention to MSB of the original value, and mask the result as required. Thanks!

Comment: @sol4me Yes, for `long` you would use `msb` of 63, and add `L` to the constant `1` (i.e. `(1L << msb)`) so that the expression is interpreted as a 64-bit `long`. Of course `inverse` would need to be declared `long` as well.

Comment: It looks like `msb = 32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(val)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using bitwise negation:

```
private int flipBits(int n) {
     return ~n;
}
```

Comment: note that this will also flip the sign bit, resulting in -5 rather than 3.

Comment: It was my initial try but it will also reverte the sign bit , for e.g. System.out.println(~4); //-5 , expected 3

Comment: Removing the sign bit is easy: just bitwise and the number with `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: @fge do you mean `~n&Integer.MAX_VALUE`? that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow not sure of the priority of the operators here, but that would be, with parens, `~(n & Integer.MAX_VALUE)`.

Comment: @fge i don't understand why that would work, and, unless i'm misunderstanding you, it isn't: http://ideone.com/s3Eavu

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow I was only talking about removing the sign bit; and this definitely works. Try and print the binary value of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(4);
        binaryString = binaryString.replaceAll("1", "-");
        binaryString = binaryString.replaceAll("0", "1");
        binaryString = binaryString.replaceAll("-", "0");
```

Only 3 lines of code to convert...

Comment: Three lines of code = three regex searches performed, which are way slower than a simple loop.

Comment: @BackSlash +1 you hit the point thats why i didn't used replaceAll in my original post

Comment: [HERE](http://www.browxy.com/SavedCode/24946) it is a little demo, if you want to see the difference

Answer (score 0):

BigInteger allows you to use a number of arbitrary length. The way to find the negation is to find the max value possible given the input length and substract the input value from it

```
   //you might want to validate that the string really is a binary number string
    BigInteger myNum = new BigInteger(inputStr, 2);
    BigInteger max = new BigInteger("2");
    max = max.pow(inputStr.length()).subtract(new BigInteger("1"));
    BigInteger ans = max.substract(myNum);
```